# Add separator text to Angular JSON data output in view

Tags: angularjs, text

not sure I have asked the question correctly, the essence of what I need to do is in my view where I have specified for eg {{car.price}}, add a space as a thousands separator.

Not sure more info can be provided but I am more than willing to supply any that is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use currency filter that is available in angularjs
just add this line in your code

```
{{ car.price| currency }}
```

Answer (score 0):

use currency filter

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}
```

or JS

```
 $filter('currency')(amount, symbol, fractionSize)
```

for example:

```
{{car.price | currency:"₹":0}}
```

fractionSize is Number of decimal places to round the amount.